# What Law is this Using

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

IGNORE THIS

Excuse the tags (idk where this goes, and I keep using the wrong words to search up on google),

I just forgot what law this step is using.

$$\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-x} = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$

This makes sense, but I just want to know what law this is using.

Comment: That does not hold.

Comment: It doesn't look like what you've written is true... Try plugging in $x = e$ on both sides, do you get the same answer?

Comment: Oh god, you are right. My teacher's note is must be wrong. Let me see where their conclusion is coming from.

Comment: From the law that $x=2$?

Comment: No, I think they took a solution from a past question and accidently applied it here.

Comment: "This makes sense"  No, it doesn't!  $\frac {\ln 13}{13^2 -13} \ne \frac {\ln 13}{13}$!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x}=\frac{\ln x}{x} \iff x\ln x = (x^2-x)\ln x  \iff x=x^2-x
$$
Solving $x=x^2-x$, we get
$$
x^2-2x=x(x-2)=0
$$
However, the solution $x=0$ is not valid (why?), and so we are left with $x=2$. So $\ln x/(x^2-x)=\ln x/(x)$ does not hold in general.